# The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly - System.Exception: The acceptable value for AspNetCoreModuleHostingModel property is either

Tags: asp.net-core

I get

> 'The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly. System.Exception: The acceptable value for AspNetCoreModuleHostingModel property is either "InProcess" or "OutOfProcess".'

error while publishing an ASP.NET Core 2.2.0 application (actually it is the included sample application) for win-x64 environment. Both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 gives the same error. I am working on Windows 10. What should I do to solve this?
Last part of publish Output is:

```
c:\users\engin\source\repos\NetCoreWebApplication2\NetCoreWebApplication2\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\PubTmp\Out\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.200-preview-009648\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(49,5): Hata MSB4018: "TransformWebConfig" görevi beklenmedik biçimde başarısız oldu.
System.Exception: The acceptable value for AspNetCoreModuleHostingModel 
 property is either "InProcess" or "OutOfProcess".
   konum: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.WebConfigTransform.TransformAspNetCore(XElement aspNetCoreElement, String appName, Boolean configureForAzure, Boolean useAppHost, String extension, String aspNetCoreModuleName, String aspNetCoreHostingModel)
   konum: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.WebConfigTransform.Transform(XDocument webConfig, String appName, Boolean configureForAzure, Boolean useAppHost, String extension, String aspNetCoreModuleName, String aspNetCoreHostingModel, String environmentName)
   konum: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformWebConfig.Execute()
   konum: Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   konum: Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

2 Derleme başarısız oldu. Daha fazla ayrıntı için çıktı penceresini denetleyin.
========== Oluşturma: 1 başarılı, 0 başarısız, 0 güncel, 0 atlandı ==========
========== Yayın: 0 başarılı, 1 başarısız, 0 atlandı ==========
```

Comment: Show us your web.config.

Comment: it it empty:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

</configuration>

Comment: It's a known bug: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/437 that they have fixed (even though it's not marked as such), but the fix might not be released yet. I'd suggest you switch to a non-Preview version of the .NET Core SDK (current stable version is 2.2.101).

Comment: Thank you. But I get the same error on 2.2.101 version. How can I apply this fix to my environment? As I see this error only occurs on Turkish machines.

Comment: Just remove the `Web.Config` file from our project, that is what is causing the issue and you don't really need that.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would suggest disabling web.config transforms altogether.  In an ASP.Net Core project you probably do not need to transform web.configs since supplying environment variables is handled by convention with `appsettings.[Environment].json` files.

From the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2:

> To prevent the Web SDK from transforming the web.config file, use the `<IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>` property in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I got this error '"TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly.' when trying to build a docker image for dotnet core 3.0 and adding this to .csproj file solved the problem

Comment: This is fixed my issue

Comment: worked for me, thanks!!!It seems this problem occured after I updated visual studio code...

Comment: worked on .net core 2.1

Answer (score 54):

I had the same problem and found the solution

In the `csproj` file, find following line and delete.

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Comment: If you plan to host on IIS, removing this line would be a hit to performance: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22

Comment: It worked for me, May I know the reason of deletion

Comment: Shouldn't have to do this unless you don't want it to run in process.

Comment: @Kellad: Please mark Barış Bar's answer as *the* answer!

Comment: I have the same question i.e May I know the reason of deletion? and what will be the possible impact of it from QA to Production?

Answer (score 34):

Had the same issue on .net core 2.2.104. Update the section to this:

`<AspNetCoreHostingModelV2>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModelV2>`

Note the **V2** addition.

Comment: While this seems to work, it will probably have to change for .NET Core 3 as well. It is likely that your Web.config file was generated with this handler that would make this redundant I think: `<handlers><add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" /></handlers>`. Either works.

Comment: @Kody your answer is the correct one! (at least for me)

Comment: AspNetCoreHostingModelV2 is meaningless, you could try AspNetCoreHostingModelV100 is ok. Simply just remove it.

Comment: @namvo you have oped my eyes. I was actually thinking this issue has been fixed in V2 version but actually this property becomes unknown when you change it's name. Thank you.

But I'm still looking for an answer what will be the impact of removing it?

Answer (score 15):

The answer @Barış Bar provided is working but can cause future errors. There is a bug about UpperCases. Just change `InProcess` in `csproj` file with lowercase

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>inprocess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

It is said that the bug will be corrected in VS 2019.

[InProcess or OutOfProcess](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/403584/on-trk-os-create-aspnet-core-22net-core-project-pu.html)

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: It hasn't been fixed with VS 2019 so far, plus Mayk's solution doesn't work. Both Remco's and Barış Bar's solutions work, though.

Comment: I tried it with lowercase but it's not working on my end using latest MSBuild (16.6.0.22303) of VS 2019. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 14):

Just add this line to your web.config file

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me. I had this line already but had to change `AspNetCoreModule` to `AspNetCoreModuleV2`. Using .NET Core 3.1 web api with a web.config for custom HTTP headers.

Answer (score 3):

For me, there was a permission issue which is why, while publishing, a transformation task was running on `web.config` file. That file did not had access for normal user.

Closing Visual Studio and running it as Administrator then publishing the project worked for me or you can try on setting the correct permissions for the problematic file.

After successfully publishing the project once with administrator privileges, visual studio started working with normal users as well (weird though but good).

---

**UPDATE:**

Stumbled into the same problem again, and this time it was not resolved by the above solution, I had to check back the project directory and some of the files were marked `Read-Only` had to change it to get it working. I suppose this is a problem with the `TFS` which gets the files and sets them as `Read-Only`.

Comment: TFS-related issues like for me was the accidentally engaged web.config file in tfs and after checking in, the file was read-only and caused problem. I checked it out and excluded it from the project and that worked. @Jamshaid K. Thanks very much for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I had a project in `TFS`, due to some issues, the `TFS` went down and when I made it go online again, it failed to publish the project, while the debugging worked fine. It caused the error (`The TransformWebConfig task failed unexpectedly`).

After checking the output window, it seemed some files were not accessible to visual studio, or were protected. So, it was because of the `TFS`, all or most of the files in the project were set as `Read-Only` which is why Visual Studio couldn't transform those files.

Removing the `Read-Only` flag from the project fixed the publishing problem.

Answer (score 1):

My .NET Core 2.2 application build was failing on Jenkins but it was working fine on local machine. 
Error: error MSB4018: The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly.

Fix: Removed below line from .csproj file
`<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`

Comment: @Raza what will be the impact of removing this property?

Answer (score 0):

find the project file (.csproj) and update this code
`<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`

to this

`<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the .csproj file did it for me:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading your .net core version from 3.1 to higher framework, please check web.config aspNetCore node

The attribute `hostingModel` should be `inprocess` (all small case) vs `InProcess` in .netcore 3.1 framework

This change worked for me and able to publish my project.

Answer (score 0):

After updating from 17.8.7 to 17.9.3 I had to change web.config from InProcess to inprocess.