# Publishing ASP.NET Core app from Visual Studio 2022 to Azure does not work without checking out web.config

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-config, visual-studio-2022

When I try to publish my ASP.NET Core app from VS 2022 (latest version) to Azure, the publishing fails in case the projects `web.config` file is not checked out.

After manually checking out this file, publishing works.

How can I make publishing work without the manual step? (I can not switch to github and I can not use continuous publishing)

Comment: Which web.config file?

Comment: The web.config file from the project. Which i use to configure a small part of iis.

Comment: Is it contains any transformation logic?

Comment: No. All it has is this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
     <rule name="Redirect baustatik.com to die.de" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*?)\.baustatik\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.die.de/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
     
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>

Comment: @ThomasWoelfer - How you are publishing your webapp

Comment: In Visual Studio, i right-click and choose "publish". That opens the publishing window where one can set options for publishing and press another "publish" button that does the actual publishing.

Comment: Thanks. This saves me few hours without having to disable web.config transform.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have mentioned this issue elsewhere and provided the details below.

> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(50,5): Error MSB4018: The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\workspaces\websites.core\websites\www.die.de\obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\Out\web.config' is denied."

While publishing the app, a transformation task was running on web.config file. According to the error message, I think the problem is related to permissions.

**Suggestion**

*1. Restart Visual Studio and running it as Administrator, then publish it.*

*2. I see that your project is on the C drive, check if you have enough permissions to access it, and check if the current web.config file is set to read-only.*

*3. Also I see a practice, you can try it. You can prevent the generation of web.config files at compile and publish time. Then you can copy and paste the web.config file to wwwroot path manually. Remember not to enable `Delete all existing files prior to publish`.*

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Related Link:**

[`The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943601/the-transformwebconfig-task-failed-unexpectedly-system-exception-the-accept)

Comment: This has nothing todo with admin rights. It has to do with the web.config file beeing read-only while under source control. The copy in the out directory is read-only also, because vs does not remove this flag. That is the core of the problem.

Also, "not enough space" in drive c isn't the problem. (it it was, no other file could be generated while the projects gets compiled.).

Preventing the generation of web.confg files doesn't help. Yes, it won't be generated and the deploy works. However, the web app will not start because required confgurations for asp.net are missing.

Comment: @ThomasWoelfer The third point is the wrokaround, that's why I suggestion you can copy and paste the web.config  under wwwroot route.

Comment: Well, yes, i could do this. However, if i do this and the "default" for web.config changes, i won't notice and keep copying the "wrong" version. so as long as devdiv is not fixeing this, i'd rather keep my web.config checked out.